# ¿Como puedo entrar desde mi terminal al XAMPP en Mac?

Tags: xampp, terminal, macos

Quiero entrar desde la terminal al paquete **htdocs** y después a mi paquete de código.

[image: mpp]

pero al ingresar **cd opt**, no funciona, al inspeccionar el paquete me muestra la ruta siguiente: **nfs://192.168.64.2/opt/lampp/htdocs** pero en ninguna de esas rutas me da acceso.

Este es el panel del XAMPP en donde muestra la ruta en donde se encuentran montados los paquetes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto también la ruta completa de la carpeta: **nfs://192.168.64.2/opt/lampp/htdocs/crm**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: intenta con `cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/` es importante que pongas / despues del cd

Comment: No funciona, manda este error: -bash: cd: /opt/lampp/htdocs/: No such file or directory

Comment: cd ~/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs

Comment: No le hagas hermano, te lo agradezco! Lo pones como Respuesta y te califico como correcto? Para subir tu reputación bro!

Comment: pa luego es tarde :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto debe funcionar:

```
cd ~/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs
```

Answer (score 0):

Esa ruta que pones, es una unidad de red (NTFS), por lo cual, la única manera de acceder es vía ssh. para poder acceder necesitas de un usuario y una contraseña.

La orden es la siguiente:

```
ssh usuario@192.168.64.2
```

y cuando accedas te pedirá la contraseña